# Change the Cut, Copy, Paste shortcut to the custom slots in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

Currently, I am working on an editor program. I want to assign three shortcut keys  (QKeySequence::Cut), (QKeySequence::Copy) and (QKeySequence::Paste) to my customized functions. However, it does not work as my expectation.

For testing, I open the "Application Example" from QtCreator. Then, I try to disable all the shortcut keys as following:

```
//cutAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Cut);    
connect(cutAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), textEdit, SLOT(cut()));

copyAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/copy.png"), tr("&Copy"), this);
//copyAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Copy);

connect(copyAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), textEdit, SLOT(copy()));

pasteAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/paste.png"), tr("&Paste"), this);
//pasteAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Paste);
```

Surprisingly, the shortcut keys still working as before.

Another test is that:

1. connect all the actions to customized slots.
2. assign all the key sequences to the actions which have already connected to my customized slots.

Then, my result is

1. Click Cut, Copy, Paste on toolbar go to my customized slots.
2. The shortcut key works independently with my customized slots.

Any advice are welcome. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You do not override the default action, you just add your custom actions to the default behavior

Comment: And by the way, it's not a good practice to override default shortcut

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I want to override the default action is that the default action is only works text, meanwhile I want to make copy/paste text and other things like html element. I have found some thing in http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18189  and  http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29988-Cannot-override-copy-shortcut . However, I still want a solution for this problem.

Comment: Then why don't you connect the slot then override the clipboard content ?

Comment: I am working on an Web editor program, thus I want to do the following actions:
- If text is selected, then copy/paste shortcut is normal because it is implemented default.
- The problem comes when I want to make a copy/paste shortcut for html tag. For ex: user clicks on the text box, which is equivalent to <div> tag, to select it. Then, I want to copy the whole <div> element to clipboard using Ctrl+C, and go to another page, "Ctrl+V" for append that <div> to the html source code.

Therefore, I want to override the default slots, not the content in clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the way to override the default shortcut, thanks to the code of Sigil.

I use the following code:

Delacre a new action in header:

```
  QShortcut &m_Paste1;
```

Then, in the constructor of class:

```
m_Paste1(*(new QShortcut(QKeySequence(QKeySequence::Paste), this, 0, 0, Qt::WidgetShortcut))),
```

Finally, connect it to your own slot

```
connect(&m_Paste1, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(paste()));
```